# CMake does not build the added sub-directory first

Tags: c++, cmake, poco-libraries

I am writing a C++ project that uses [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/) Net library. I use CMake to configure the project.

I would like to add Poco as a sub-directory to my project so that it is built in my main project. Here is my shortened main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(FunProj)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
      set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()

message(STATUS "Building in ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} mode...")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(HEADER_FILES IDataProvider.h DataProvider.h)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
                 DataProvider.cpp)

set(POCO_STATIC ON)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(poco)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/poco/Net/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/poco/Foundation/include)

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/poco/lib)

add_executable(FunProj ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${EXEC_NAME} PocoNet)
```

When I run cmake it configures everything including Poco but when I run make it does not compile the Poco libraries. It only compiles the main.o and DataProvider.o and then the linker fails with an error that libPocoNet.a does not exist.

What is the problem and how may one solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: In the Poco project there is `Poco::Net` or, short version, `Net` library targets, but there is no `PocoNet` target. So, the linker tries to find `PocoNet` library, and fails.

Comment: Maybe I understood this wrong but doesn't target_link_libraries look for the actual library? In this case libPocoNet.a

Comment: Maybe I understood this wrong but doesn't target_link_libraries look for the actual library? In this case libPocoNet.a. I will test it as soon as I can.

Comment: Command `target_link_libraries` works both with *targets* and *files*. If you have the target, describing the library, its usage is preferred. In your case, linking with `Poco::Net` or `Net` would eliminate needing of `include_directories` and `link_directories`. Moreover, when link with a *target*, CMake automatically creates a dependency to all actions, which builds given target. In case of linking with a file, target-level dependency isn't created automatically. This is why CMake doesn't build PocoNet before your executable.

Comment: This actually worked. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.